# Get data from specific date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to collect data from specific dates in a Google Sheets. For example, I want to get the data from January only:

[image: sample data]

Is this possible?

Comment: Filter on January and copy/paste?

Comment: @Jerry -1 for your comment. That's why this question needs to be migrated to Web Applications.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I'd rather vote to close it for lack of "minimal understanding of the problem being solved" than to move it first and vote to close it there; filters are one of the key features of spreadsheets.

Comment: @Jerry that's why you need to migrate. On Web Applications they  will get a proper response and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula to do that.

### Formula

```
=FILTER(DATA!A2:D5, MONTH(DATA!A2:A5)=1)
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Filter by January](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1gJ9hAk4rxImPDjFLPKnwNNAUbXv3PCBqjYvRiDWE-EU/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

FILTER may make more sense but with [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) is possible:

```
=query(B:E,"where month(B)=0")
```

for which `Date` is assumed to be in ColumnB.

A little shorter but the main difference is really whether or not headers are included.